# Cannot create a folder in a list

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to create a folder in a list, the following does not work:

```cs
var folder = new DriveItem
{
    Name = plan.Title,
    Folder = new Folder()
};

await graphServiceClient
    .Sites["ourdomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/ITOddeleni:"]
    .Lists["Planner"]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .Children
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(folder);
```

I am using these as parameters for other calls, can I leave it be or does it expect GUID?

**EDIT 1**

The ERROR quote is Code:

```
BadRequest
Message: Url specified is invalid.
```

So I assume the `.Sites` and `.Lists` should have GUID but after replacing the Site URL with Id of site and ID of the list I get the following:

```
Code: -1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
Message: Cannot find resource for the request Microsoft.FileServices.FileService/Sites('50cb05fa-27f9-45bf-a5f3-5f82e0e2eb00')/lists('ad52e785-c9b7-4106-af7b-a3394462875c')/drive/.
```

**EDIT 2**

I have tried to create the folder via Graph Explorer, found the content type ID for the folder on a list and used POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/50cb05fa-27f9-45bf-a5f3-5f82e0e2eb00/lists/ad52e785-c9b7-4106-af7b-a3394462875c/items

With this Request body

```
{
"Title" : "Test2",
"contentType": { "id": "0x012000FC4989A03C9F7845AD8C206E2F47A0FD" }
}
```

Now the folder gets created, but the call requires Title, but does not accept Name, which results in created folder without Name (title). Edit: It does accept "name"with lowercase N, but still the name is not shown in the list. Tried to send it as "BaseName", "FileLeafRef" and some other internal names of Folder, but without success.

[image]

Comment: "does not work" isn't very specific. Please include the complete request and response in your question.

Comment: Is this a document library?

Comment: it is just a list

Comment: Can you please put the question out of the hold?

Answer (score 0):

Without an error message, it isn't clear exactly what is happening here. That said, the syntax for creating a new folder should look like this:

```cs
var folder = new DriveItem
{
    Name = plan.Title,
    Folder = new Folder { },
    @microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior = "rename"
};
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, will try tomorrow. And yeah sorry mine current project does not reply the error quote, will try to implement that as well.

Comment: added the error quote