# Cannot create a folder in a SharePoint Online List

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

Previous question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185537/cannot-create-a-folder-in-a-list) closed by our heroic&pesky moderators who rush in to mark everything wrong, but once you edit it to meet their deviant needs, nobody votes to reopen it, because they already did their part...

So please, can someone try to explain me, how to properly create a Folder in SharePoint Online List?

I've tried to create it first using C# SDK, which did not work.

```
var folder = new DriveItem
{
Name = plan.Title,
Folder = new Folder()
};

await graphServiceClient
.Sites["ourdomain.sharepoint.com:/sites/ITOddeleni:"]
.Lists["Planner"]
.Drive
.Root
.Children
.Request()
.AddAsync(folder);
```

Then I started to play around with Graph Explorer, found out the ContentType ID for the folder and tried to create it as an item with ContentType specified.

This is the JSON Request Header, that resulted in creation of the folder in the list, but it has not name, as folder behaves differently in SharePoint than the item.

```
{
"Title" : "Test2",
"contentType": { "id": "0x012000FC4989A03C9F7845AD8C206E2F47A0FD" }
}
```

I've tried to change the "Title" for "Name", "FileLeafRef" and whatsoever could be Folders internal name for Title, but could not figure it out. It accepted all the request headers, but still the name of the created folder was blank.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

EDIT:

I've tried Vadim's suggestion, and the folder really got created, and it seems on the 1st look that it carries the name you specify in the code. But also it carries some generated name, see the right side of the picture.

[image: See the created folder]

Once you open the folder, you loose your name until you refresh the page on the level where the folder sits. This is how it looks when you open the folder.

[image]

I have also tried to add name/Name besides the title, but it returns
"Message: Field 'Name' is not recognied" both lower and uppercase.

Comment: It would be useful to show how each option you tried failed. The C# example should work, assuming the list in question is a document library.

Comment: If it were a document library, I would say it is document library, this is just a list. C# code returns: Code: -1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ResourceNotFoundException
Message: Cannot find resource for the request Microsoft.FileServices.FileService/Sites('50cb05fa-27f9-45bf-a5f3-5f82e0e2eb00')/lists('ad52e785-c9b7-4106-af7b-a3394462875c')/drive/.

Comment: Other methonds were called in Graph Explorer, returning no error, but the created folder has no name. As I am creating it as item with contentType specified.

Answer (score 0):

Did You consider CSOM or it is not an option? SharePoint online best option would be to use CSOM PnP nuget [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/)

The code should look something like this:

```
    try
    {
        string siteUrl = "SiteUrl";
        AuthenticationManager authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
        using (ClientContext context = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LibName");
            context.Load(list);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Folder folder = list.RootFolder.CreateFolder("NewFolder");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log error
        throw;
    }
```

I already tested the above code with some console app and in my case the result was 
[image]

I hope it will be of any help :)

Comment: Hello Adam, thanks for your suggestion, but this should stay just Graph project, as it should be able to create the folder somehow... :-) there must be a way

Answer (score 0):

It appears folder in a *List* could be created via [`Create item` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) like this:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "Folder name goes here",
  },
  "contentType": { "id": "0x0120" }
}
```

where

- folder properties such as Title are specified via [`ListItem.Fields` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)
- to create an item of folder type, `contentType` property set to `0x0120` needs to be explicitly specified

**C# example**

```
var folderItem = new ListItem
{
    ContentType = new ContentTypeInfo()
       {
           Id = "0x0120"
       },
       Fields = new FieldValueSet()
               {
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string,object>
                    {
                        {
                            "Title", folderName
                        }
                    }
                }
};

await graphClient
       .Sites.Root
       .Lists["<list name or id>"]
       .Items
       .Request()
       .AddAsync(folderItem);
```

Comment: Hello Vadim, thanks for your reply :-) The folder is created, but here comes the issue. Initially it looks fine, the folder is created, it has the name specified, but once you open the folder, it's name converts to "3163_.000" in my case and stays like that until I refresh the page when it carries the name until I click on it... strange. See the edit.

Comment: @MarekKyzivát, indeed,  it appears `FileLeafRef` is getting created in the following format `<ItemId>_.000`..

Answer (score 0):

You can use two request.
First for creating item (Post)
And then for updating item (Patch) by getting id from first request.
add FileLeafRef field in patch request
Body in both requests are same. And then FileLeafRef will be not {Id}_.000 but {Title}